# Receiving data too fast from NAudio

Tags: naudio

So I'm using NAudio to receive data from the computer mic. The buffer for waveIn is 100 ms. I receive 9600 bytes per DataAvailable, which would correspond to 2 bytes per sample and for 100 ms (48000/10 samples with 2 bytes). So far so good. The problem is, however, that I receive data 20 times a second, not 10 as would be expected. I'm running a counter for every DataAvailable, and after one minute, the counter is 1200, not 600.

Anyone know why this is happening? Is there something I don't get?

```
 waveIn.DeviceNumber = selectedDevice;
 waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;                       
 waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(48000, 1);
 waveIn.StartRecording();
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the BytesRecorded value in the DataAvailable event args?

Comment: I figured out the problem, a stupid error on my part. Problem is recording was started elsewhere in code at same time.